# Using SQL Aliases on a sample database (world) does return 0

Tags: mysql

I'm learning SQL commands from w3schools.
Using MySQL workbench 8, with the world sample database.

This is how the DB looks. (first entry so you get the idea)

```html
ID NAME CountryCode District Population

1 Kabul AFG Kabol 1780000
```

And I'm using this

```html
SELECT Name, CountryCode + District AS Total
FROM world.city;
```

And the output is

```html
Kabul 0
```

and I don't get why. Is w3schools obsolete and things changed?

Comment: You are trying to add two string values (CountryCode, District) and display the sum under the Total alias, to add them both values must be numbers or you can use the CONCAT function to concat strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, CONCAT(CountryCode, District) AS Total FROM world.city;
```